# Converting a long series into a dataframe based on occurrence of specific keys in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

First, apologies if the question subjectseems vague. I will try to make it clear.
I have a Panda series like:

```
A
a1
b1
c1
B
a2
b2
c2
```

What we need is to form a dataframe where {A,B} are the values of column one, and the values following each are the values of column two. For our example, something like:

```
A    a1
A    b1
A    c1
B    a2
B    b2
B    c2
```

We have all the column one labels in a list [A,B,...].

I tried to df.apply some function, which to me seemed not at all pandorable and more like a machine level code. Anybody has an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an alternative approach which depends on membership in a labels list, and not on string parsing:

```
In [78]: labels = ["A", "B"]

In [79]: marks = s.isin(labels)

In [80]: pd.concat([s.where(marks).ffill(), s], axis=1).loc[~marks]
Out[80]: 
   0   1
1  A  a1
2  A  b1
3  A  c1
5  B  a2
6  B  b2
7  B  c2
```

---

Step by step, first we build `marks`, which is a bool Series telling us where each new section starts:

```
In [22]: marks = s.isin(labels)

In [23]: marks
Out[23]: 
0     True
1    False
2    False
3    False
4     True
5    False
6    False
7    False
dtype: bool
```

Originally I was planning to use `marks.cumsum()` for groupby purposes, but it's simpler just to use `where` here.

We can then use `s.where(marks).ffill()` to get a series containing the appropriate labels:

```
In [24]: s.where(marks)
Out[24]: 
0      A
1    NaN
2    NaN
3    NaN
4      B
5    NaN
6    NaN
7    NaN
dtype: object

In [25]: s.where(marks).ffill()
Out[25]: 
0    A
1    A
2    A
3    A
4    B
5    B
6    B
7    B
dtype: object
```

After that, we just concatenate:

```
In [26]: pd.concat([s.where(marks).ffill(), s], axis=1)
Out[26]: 
   0   1
0  A   A
1  A  a1
2  A  b1
3  A  c1
4  B   B
5  B  a2
6  B  b2
7  B  c2
```

And use `.loc[~marks]` to keep the rows which *don't* mark the start of a new section:

```
In [27]: pd.concat([s.where(marks).ffill(), s], axis=1).loc[~marks]
Out[27]: 
   0   1
1  A  a1
2  A  b1
3  A  c1
5  B  a2
6  B  b2
7  B  c2
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `pd.Series.str.extract`

```
d1 = s.str.extract('([A-Z])*(.+)*', expand=True)
d1[0].ffill(inplace=True)
d1.dropna()

   0   1
1  A  a1
2  A  b1
3  A  c1
5  B  a2
6  B  b2
7  B  c2
```

Answer (score 1):

One way using `isin`

```
In [3750]: cond = s.isin(L)

In [3751]: pd.concat([s.where(cond, np.nan).ffill(), s[~cond]], axis=1).dropna()
Out[3751]:
   0   1
1  A  a1
2  A  b1
3  A  c1
5  B  a2
6  B  b2
7  B  c2
```

---

Details

```
In [3752]: s
Out[3752]:
0     A
1    a1
2    b1
3    c1
4     B
5    a2
6    b2
7    c2
dtype: object

In [3753]: L
Out[3753]: ['A', 'B']
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some clever and elegant answers posted above. Just for comparison's sake, I also tried out an alternate reduce-based method that is faster in micro-benchmarks. It runs well under a ms on my machine (~5x faster than a couple of the Pandas operator based solutions).

```
In [7]: # Setup test data
   ...: import itertools as it
   ...: labels = list('ABCDEFGH')
   ...: rawlist = [[l.lower() + str(i) for l in labels] for  i in range(1,8)]
   ...: s = pd.Series(list(it.chain(*[[k] + vlist for k, vlist in zip(labels, rawlist)])))

In [8]: s.head(12)
Out[8]: 
0      A
1     a1
2     b1
3     c1
4     d1
5     e1
6     f1
7     g1
8     h1
9      B
10    a2
11    b2

In [10]: # Setup reduction function
    ...: def _myreducer(acc, x):
    ...:     """acc: [curr_label, [(label, related entry)]]""" 
    ...:     curr_label, label_entry_pair = acc
    ...:     if x in labels: 
    ...:         acc[0] = x  # curr_label is now x
    ...:     else:
    ...:         acc[1].append( (curr_label, x) ) # append (label, entry) pair
    ...:     return acc
    ...: 
    ...: reduced_tuple = reduce(_myreducer, s, [None, []])

In [11]: pd.DataFrame(reduced_tuple[1]).head(12)
    ...: 
Out[11]: 
    0   1
0   A  a1
1   A  b1
2   A  c1
3   A  d1
4   A  e1
5   A  f1
6   A  g1
7   A  h1
8   B  a2
9   B  b2
10  B  c2
11  B  d2
```